# How can I tell the PSS to shut up?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I've been having lots of fun with Pokemon Y.  I'm in the middle of adventuring, and all of a sudden, the PSS tells me about this new feature...that I already knew about, and have used.  Looking through the options available, I don't see any setting that turns this off.

How can I inform the PSS that I am aware of the features it offers, and to stop alerting me to them?

Comment: I thought I was the only one annoyed by this :/. I think you can restrict who can message you (having the internet turned on I seem to get a trade/battle request every 10 mins or so), but I haven't seen an option to turn off the "help" text

Comment: The only way I have been able to get these to stop is by either turning off my wireless on my 3DS or just by scrolling over to another screen, like the training screen.

Comment: Still doesn't shut up in ORAS

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can, but you can switch to Super Training or Pokemon Aime when you are not using it

Answer (score 0):

In Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire you can go to the bottom right side of the page and click on the back sign to exit the PSS screen.

Answer (score -1):

Well the way I made it shut up was to just go on the add and use it I don't know about you but I also have Y and that is what worked for me.